# distribution of the sum of the largest k of n throws

Tags: probability

Suppose we throw a die $n$ times and sum the largest $k$ values, then what is the distribution of the value we obtain?

Comment: not sure if this has a name... would be very glad to know if someone enlightens me

Comment: I would be surprised at anything other than asymptotic estimates, already "the largest $n$ (all) is in that category, without the complication of largest.

Answer (score 1):

This is I think related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355820/expected-value-of-the-minimum-discrete-case)

I'm sorry I cannot comment yet, i think this is more a comment than an answer, but here is how i feel things :
Let X be the sum of the best k results

If n is high enough, you will have n/6 results of each face (Law of Large Numbers)

- If $0 < k < \frac{n}{6}$ then $X = 6*k$ (pretty intuitive since there is more than k sixes)
- If $\frac{n}{6} < k < \frac{2*n}{6}$ then $X = (6*\frac{n}{6}) + 5*(k-\frac{n}{6})$
- If $\frac{2*n}{6} < k < \frac{3*n}{6}$ then $X = (6*\frac{n}{6}) + (5*\frac{n}{6}) + 4*(k-\frac{2*n}{6})$

And so on up to $k = n$ where $X = n*3.5$ (since 3.5 is the mean for a die roll)

I know you asked for distribution and this is only expected value but once again, i cannot comment yet. Should I just delete this answer ?

Comment: Loi des Grands Nombres = Law of large numbers. // I understand next to nothing to the rest of your post.

Comment: Is that because I don't make myself clear ? For the reasoning, draw a graph of how the results are distributed and watch the best k results