# How to cheat at Dungeons and Dragons Character Generation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

When creating a new character in Dungeons and Dragons, one will typically roll three dice to generate a score for an attribute such as Strength, Agility, Constitution, etc.   The probability for any particular outcome for the rolls, 3 through 18, follows a certain distribution.  Let us suppose that instead of simply taking the result of the roll, that we decide to cheat, and roll three times, taking the best result as our attribute score.  How do we calculate the new probability distribution, and the resulting expectation value?  How would we extend this to a generic scenario where we know the base probability distribution, and want to reroll n number of times?

Comment: Is the highest score the best result here?

Comment: yep, higher the score the better. Though in the generic case, lowest could be selected for. It's basically a question of, "If we intentionally skew the results, how does it affect the overall probability?"

Comment: This might be relevant [When rolling multiple dice, what is the average value if you only keep the highest roll?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010729/when-rolling-multiple-dice-what-is-the-average-value-if-you-only-keep-the-highe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that in general you are after the distribution of $M:=\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ where the $X_i$ are iid random variables (correct me if I am wrong).

The CDF of $M$ can easily be expressed in the CDF of the $X_i$:

$$F_M(x)=P(X_1\leq x,\dots,X_n\leq x)=F(x)^n$$

In the special case you mention we find: $$p_k=P(M=k)=F^3(k)-F^3(k-1)$$ for $k=3,\dots,18$ so that: $$\mathbb EM=\sum_{k=3}^{18} k[F^3(k)-F^3(k-1)]$$

Alternatively you could use:$$\mathbb{E}M=\sum_{k=0}^{17}P\left\{ M>k\right\} =\sum_{k=0}^{17}1-F^{3}\left(k\right)$$

Comment: the case of IID random variables is useful, but ultimately I'd like to know how to apply the answer to any case where I know the probability distribution.  In my real-world case that led to the question, the probabilities follow a binomial distribution.

Comment: What you want ultimately is much. Too much, I would say. It makes your question a candidate for closing it as "too broad".

Comment: I think this generalizes to what I'm looking for, as long as the distribution in question has an easily defined CDF, which the binomial distribution has.  Does that sound right?

Comment: If indeed the CDF is a coöperating one then this can be used.

Answer (score 2):

If $p(x)$ is the probability of rolling at least $x$, then $p_n(x)$ the probability of rolling at least $x$ on $n$ attempts is $1 - (1 - p(x))^n$.

The probability of not rolling at least $x$ is $(1 - p(x))$.  Doing it $n$ times in a row is $(1 - p(x))^n$. Failing to rolls less than $x$ $n$ times is then $1 - (1 - p(x))^n$.

So for your example, rolling 3 dice:

$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10  \\ \hline
1.000&0.995&0.981&0.954&0.907&0.838&0.741&0.625\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
11 &12 &13 &14 &15 &16 &17 &18 \\ \hline
0.500&0.375&0.259&0.162&0.093&0.046&0.019&0.005\end{array}$$

And with 3 attempts:

$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10 \\ \hline
1.000&1.000&1.000&1.000&0.999&0.996&0.983&0.947\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
11 &12 &13 &14 &15 &16 &17 &18 \\ \hline
0.875&0.756&0.594&0.412&0.253&0.133&0.055&0.014\end{array}$$

So you still only have a 1.4% chance of getting that perfect 18.